# Google play dev problems

Tags: java

I made my apps  form appyet i add admob to my apps after 20 days i recive a NOTIFICATIONS Like [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sp3X.png) and a text :

Security Alert Your application uses a version of MoPub which presents a security flaw . Please see this article from the Google Help Center for more information , including the time you have to correct the flaw. Concerns the version 5 of the APK file. Access the APK page

Finally I Dont understand, Help Me Pleas  !!!

Comment: Security Alert Your application uses a version of MoPub which presents a security flaw . Please see this article from the Google Help Center for more information , including the time you have to correct the flaw. Concerns the version 5 of the APK file. Access the APK page

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://forum.appyet.com/index.php?threads/mopub-security-vulnerability.1145/)